# Getting Facebook Conversions API error - " Diagnostic Issues Found "

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-ads, conversions-api

I had recently implemented Facebook Conversions API in Facebook Ads Manager for an wordpress woocommerce website. All the test events are showing up in activity. However i am gettin this error - " Diagnostic Issues Found " in Facebook PageView Event in facebook.

[image]

Last Week I did tried fixing this issue it by adding this piece of code in facebook page view event in Google Tag Manager. Don't know if it created more problems. Please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Per their documentation for [eventID](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/deduplicate-pixel-and-server-events/#deduplication-best-practices), seems like you should be setting eventID as part of final parameter list. More like,

```
fbq('track', 'PageView', {}, {eventID: {{event_id}} });
```

Also if you are using Woocommerce and Google Tag Manager, please make sure the events fired by both use the same `event_id` value

Comment: Thanks so much for your help mate ... just trying to understand your solution ...why did you add an empty dictionary in there ..

Comment: also i am not using facebook for woocommerce yet since the no of products i am promoting is less 6 .. so i have not linked woocommerce for facebook and i am doing it manually even for remarketing purposes